# mysql connection id (thread_id)

Tags: mysql

Does mySQL use a specific connection id (thread_id) range for user connections?  I notice all the connections I make are in the 50's range like 55,56.  But there are other connections (not mine) that are 8 and 9.

Or is there a table I can select only user conenction id's?

The query Im working with is:

```
USE mysql;
SELECT * FROM general_log 
WHERE command_type='query' AND argument REGEXP ('^(SELECT|INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE).*')  AND thread_id != CONNECTION_ID()
ORDER BY event_time DESC;
```

but id like to filter out all the none user querys.

---

**EDIT**

I found another table, so now my query looks like this, although the `processlist` obviously only gives active connection details and I still cant tell if it's a user or a system process which made the connection

```
USE mysql;
#TRUNCATE general_log;
SELECT * FROM general_log AS gl
LEFT JOIN information_schema.PROCESSLIST AS pl ON pl.ID = gl.thread_id
WHERE command_type='query' AND argument REGEXP ('^(SELECT|INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE).*') AND thread_id != CONNECTION_ID()
ORDER BY event_time DESC;
```

Comment: Nothing to say. I even cannot find this information in documentation.

Comment: i tried the documentation also. Didnt find anything...

Comment: Belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your initial question is "no".

All connections share the same connection id range so that number will not tell you anything useful about the connection.

If you want to exclude certain users (maybe "repl" or "system user") then you can do that with the user_host column:

```
USE mysql;
SELECT * FROM general_log 
WHERE command_type='query' 
AND argument REGEXP ('^(SELECT|INSERT|DELETE|UPDATE).*')  
AND thread_id != CONNECTION_ID()
AND user_host NOT IN (...)
ORDER BY event_time DESC;
```